# Term for single-word nouns

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

A noun or adjective that defines all single-word nouns (i.e. pronouns, proper, collective). This excludes multi-word nouns such as compound-nouns.

> - Noun: Single-word nouns are called ______.
> - Adjective: Single-word nouns are called ______-nouns.

Comment: A noun is a word.  An acronym is not multi-word.  Nouns play multiple roles in English, and multi-word entities may also play those roles.  They are called noun phrases.

Comment: @Jim you're right, I don't know what I was thinking when I changed my question

Comment: How about *simple nouns*?

Comment: "Single word" is used with reference to both hyphenated and closed compounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the word you are seeking is "simple".  If a noun is used instead of a noun phrase, that noun is a simple noun.  A simple noun is not define by the number of words, but by the fact that it is not a noun phrase.  However, in almost all cases, a simple noun is one word.